# Snackbar under BottomNavigation

Tags: android, layout, bottomnavigationview, snackbar

I'm trying to show to user a Snackbar it RideFragment which is in MainActivity. But the BottomNavigation overlaps the Snackbar, so the Snackbar is not readable/visible at all. I saw some similar problems solved by using additional CoordinatorLayouts, but I can get it working.

Here is how it look like:
[image]

Here is the XML for MainActivity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".main.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Can someone help me?

And here is the XML for RideFragment (for Rides tab)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".main.RidesFragment">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/offerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
    android:text="Offer"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Search"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/offerButton" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your `BottomNavigationView` this attribute:

```
app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"
```

And invoke you `SnackBar` with container as a view attibute:

```
Snackbar.make(container, "Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: It kinda works, but the results is as follows:
[link](https://imgur.com/wVGOfkm)

Can we make it the other way around?

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted it under the bar. In that case you can remove that attribute and display snackbar on framecontainer view. It should be above the bottom bar then.

Comment: Most tutorial forget to mention the Sanckbar.make(container part. Thx.